# Limit point is limit of convergent sequence

Tags: general-topology, limits

Suppose we're working in a topological space $X$ that's not necessarily a metric space, and suppose $x$ is a limit point of $S\subset X$ (in the general topological sense: there's no neighborhood $N$ of $x$ such that $(N-\{x\})\cap S=\emptyset$). Then is it necessarily the case that there exists $x_n\in S$ such that $x_n\to x$ (i.e. for each neighborhood $N$ of $x$, $x_n\in N$ for all $n$ large enough)?

This is clearly true for metric spaces and easy to show. I feel like it should be true in general, but can't seem to reach the conclusion from the general, non-metric space, definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not true in general.  For example, let $X$ be the ordinals $\le x$ (the first uncountable ordinal) with the order topology, and $S$ the set of all countable ordinals.  Then $x$ is a limit point of $S$, but a limit of a sequence of countable ordinals is a countable ordinal.